# How to improve oddly designed Pergola structure stability?

Tags: structural, construction, pergola

I recently removed a 1980's hottub set above my deck, this removal caused me to realize some of the exterior hottub seating turned out to be a bit more structural supporting then first thought.

I am currently planning to remove all of the treated wood and only leave the Pergola standing, then add knee braces at the bases of each for post. Four would be added to the inside base, one for each post, then another four near the top, the lag bolts would need to go through all three pieces of wood for the top knee braces. See last image for the plan.

Knee brace near the bottom isn't a tripping hazard as it will be covered later. Currently, I can cause the entire structure to wiggle by pushing on a beam. Do note that one of the post is very much curved near the top.

The sketchy "support" board holding the Pergola steady attached to my house will also be removed after adding the knee braces.

Found this thread which support my idea as they two have a unusual style https://www.houzz.com/discussions/2645484/wobbly-pergola

So finally,

1. Is this a good idea?
2. Should I just tear the whole thing down and replace it?
3. Should I get someone to take a look at it, if so, what should I look for?

[image: Full view, none of the treated wood is attached to the painted wood, only a nail or two here and there]
[image: Close up of on of the post, the seating appeared to keep it steady.]
[image: Sketchy]
[image: Side view, a mess]
[image: The curve]
[image]
[image: remove this :)]

Comment: **2** - 1/2" DIA. **[through]** BOLTS TYPICAL (**MIN.**) - page "23" https://www.chicago.gov/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf And the bottom of the posts should also be done as if they're railing posts, on page "38". Then treat the box as if it were railings and bolt those to the columns (posts) too.

Comment: Right angle drill, and a 1/2" dia, 18" long arguer bit. SS nuts bolts and washers. Google *minimum edge distance* (to stay away from) for drilling holes... if it isn't obvious.

Comment: Hmm think I'm following, given those changes, do you believe it would be safe to remove the "railing" near the house to allow entry? Current plan is to finish the deck. I've added another image with the section marked in red that would be removed. @mazura
Thanks!